# Parallels Desktop Linux Mint internet connection not working

Tags: linux-mint, internet-connection, parallels

i wanted to take my first steps into a linux dist. So I got myself Parallels Desktop and downloaded Linux Mint. Now im stuck because I don't have internet connection inside my VM. The network seems to be established correctly and i can ping anything but not browse. Anyone knows this problem and can help me out? Parallels Network Settings are using "Shared Network". Im using Mint 20 and because of the problem im not able to install the necessary "parallels tools"

[image: Network Settings in Mint]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that its a problem with the version of parallels desktop from the app store. I tried my luck with the normal version of parallels desktop downloaded from their website and after setting up my linux everything works now.